# 一次元配列のキーのサフィックスを元に、二次元配列を作成したい

Tags: php

`'xxxx_数字'キー`が複数)あります。数は変動します
`'b_数字'キー`の数だけ、数字毎に分けて二次元配列へ格納したいです。

**元配列(例)**

```
$a =array (
  'あ' => 'い',
  'b_1' => 'う',
  'b_2' => 'え',
  'c_1' => 'お',
  'c_2' => 'か',
);
```

**期待している結果**

```
$z = array
(
    [0] => array //キー名サフィックスが_1のものを抽出
        (
            'b' => 'う',
            'c' => 'お',
        )

    [1] => array //キー名サフィックスが_2のものを抽出
            'b' => 'え',
            'c' => 'か',
        )
}
```

---

**試したコード**
取り敢えず、`'_1キー'`が含まれる数だけ抽出してみたのですが、期待結果を取得するためにはどうすれば良いですか？

```
array_filter($a, function($key) { 
  return strpos($key, '_1') !== false;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

Comment: 数字が 0 とか飛び飛び (1, 2, 5, 8 とか) だった場合はどうなりますか？ それとも元データも自分で作るので、それらの可能性は無いと考えて良いですか？

Comment: 数字が 0 の可能性はありません。飛び飛び の場合は昇順ソート。期待結果の一次元目キーについては(説明が抜けていますが)、(元配列キーの数値-1ではなく)0から順番に付与する意図でした

Answer (score 1, accepted):

はじめまして。別解です。
難しいのは、preg_match(正規表現)になるかなと思います。
文字をマッチさせながら構成部品を抽出できるので覚えておくと便利です。
array_walkでクロージャ使うとすこし今風な書き方ができます。

```
$a =array (
  'あ' => 'い',
  'b_1' => 'う',
  'b_2' => 'え',
  'c_1' => 'お',
  'c_2' => 'か',
);

$r=[];
array_walk($a,function($v,$k) use (&$r){
    $m=[];
    $ret = preg_match("/([a-z])_([0-9])$/",$k,$m);
    if($ret){
        $idx_a = $m[1];//1番目にマッチする([a-z])の部分
        $idx_n = (int)$m[2]-1;//2番目にマッチする([0-9])の部分
        if(!isset($r[$idx_n])) $r[$idx_n]=[];
        $r[$idx_n][$idx_a]=$v;
    }
});
```

Comment: 期待通り動作しましたが、「&$r」はどういう意味ですか？ コールバックにリファレンス変数(理解できていません)を渡している？　変数スコープ外の変数を読み込んでいるから？　array_walkだから？？

Comment: useを利用することで、クロージャ内でスコープ外の変数を操作できます。またクロージャ内で値を操作するには参照として渡してあげないといけません。PHPでは関数の引数は指定ない限り値渡しとなります。値渡しと異なり、参照渡ししたものは呼び先でも操作することができます。なぜ参照渡しかというと`別の関数で値を操作して戻す必要があるから`となります。

Comment: なるほど、クロージャ内でスコープ外の変数を変更し続けていくためですね

Answer (score 1):

`preg_match()` と `array_merge()` を使う場合。

```
$a =array (
  'あ' => 'い',
  'b_1' => 'う',
  'b_2' => 'え',
  'c_1' => 'お',
  'c_2' => 'か',
);

$z = array();
foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
  if (preg_match('/^(.+?)_(\d+)$/', $k, $m)) {
    $key = $m[2] - 1;
    if (!array_key_exists($key, $z)) $z[$key] = array();
    $z[$key] = array_merge($z[$key], array($m[1] => $v));
  }
}

var_dump($z);

=>
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["b"]=>
    string(3) "う"
    ["c"]=>
    string(3) "お"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["b"]=>
    string(3) "え"
    ["c"]=>
    string(3) "か"
  }
}
```

Comment: 期待通り動作しました。正規表現部分で、キー内に_があるもののみ取得＆分割しているわけですね。array_mergeの第1引数部分が分からないのですが、一次元配列と一次元配列を連結して二次元配列にしているのですか？？

Comment: 分かりました。$zに指定$keyが存在しなければ(二次目となる)配列を作成して、作成したその(二次目となる)配列自身と第2引数を結合しているのですね